# React-Redux, TypeError: addItem is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm fairly new to redux. I'm taking an E-Commerce site tutorial using React and Redux. 
I have a CollectionItem Component that has a button that calls an addItem function which adds the specified item to the shopping Cart.
The addItem function works for CollectionItems Component generated from CollectionPreview however it doesnt work for CollectionItems Components generated from Collections. Whenever the button is clicked i get a TypeError: addItem is not a function. 
find codes below

**CollectionItem Component**

```
import React from "react";
import "./collection.item.style.scss";
import CustomButton from "../custom-button/custom.button.component";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { addItem } from "../../redux/cart/cart.action";

export const CollectionItem = ({ item, addItem }) => {
  const { name, imageUrl, price } = item;

  return (
    <div className="CollectionItem">
      <div
        className="Image"
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `url(${imageUrl})`
        }}
      />
      <div className="footer">
        <span className="ItemName">{name}</span>
        <span className="ItemPrice">#{price}</span>
      </div>
      <CustomButton onClick={() => addItem(item)} color="outline-dark">
        Add to Cart
      </CustomButton>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapDispatchtoProps = dispatch => ({
  addItem: item => dispatch(addItem(item))
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchtoProps)(CollectionItem);
```

**CollectionPreview Component**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import CollectionItem from "../collection.item/collection.item.component";
import "./collection.preview.style.scss";

class Preview extends Component {
  render() {
    const { title, items } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="CollectionPreview">
        <h1 className="CollectionTitle">{title}</h1>
        <div className="Preview">
          {items
            .filter((item, index) => index < 4)
            .map(item => (
              <CollectionItem key={item.id} item={item} />
            ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Preview;
```

**Collection Component**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./collection.style.scss";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { selectCollection } from "../../redux/shop/shop.selector";
import { CollectionItem } from "../collection.item/collection.item.component";

class Collection extends Component {
  render() {
    const { title, items } = this.props.collections;
    return (
      <div className="collection-page">
        <h2 className="title"> {title}</h2>
        <div className="container items">
          {items.map(item => (
            <CollectionItem key={item.id} item={item} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapPropsToState = (state, ownProps) => ({
  collections: selectCollection(ownProps.match.params.collectionId)(state)
});

export default connect(mapPropsToState)(Collection);
```

**Redux Cart Action**

```
import { TOGGLE_CART } from "./cart.types";
import { ADD_ITEMS } from "./cart.types";
import { DELETE_ITEMS } from "./cart.types";
import { INCREASE_QUANTITY } from "./cart.types";
import { DECREASE_QUANTITY } from "./cart.types";

export const toggleCart = () => {
  return {
    type: TOGGLE_CART
  };
};

export const addItem = item => {
  return {
    type: ADD_ITEMS,
    payload: item
  };
};

export const deleteItem = item => {
  return {
    type: DELETE_ITEMS,
    payload: item
  };
};

export const increaseItem = item => {
  return {
    type: INCREASE_QUANTITY,
    payload: item
  };
};

export const decreaseItem = item => {
  return {
    type: DECREASE_QUANTITY,
    payload: item
  };
};
```

**Cart Reducer**

```
import { TOGGLE_CART } from "./cart.types";
import { ADD_ITEMS } from "./cart.types";
import { addItemToCart } from "./cart.utils";
import { DELETE_ITEMS } from "./cart.types";
import { deleteItemFromCart } from "./cart.utils";
import { increaseCartItem } from "./cart.utils";
import { decreaseCartItem } from "./cart.utils";
import { DECREASE_QUANTITY } from "./cart.types";
import { INCREASE_QUANTITY } from "./cart.types";

const initialState = {
  showCart: false,
  cartItems: []
};

const cartReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TOGGLE_CART:
      return {
        ...state,
        showCart: !state.showCart
      };
    case ADD_ITEMS:
      return {
        ...state,
        cartItems: addItemToCart(state.cartItems, action.payload)
      };
    case DELETE_ITEMS:
      return {
        ...state,
        cartItems: deleteItemFromCart(state.cartItems, action.payload)
      };
    case INCREASE_QUANTITY:
      return {
        ...state,
        cartItems: increaseCartItem(state.cartItems, action.payload)
      };
    case DECREASE_QUANTITY:
      return {
        ...state,
        cartItems: decreaseCartItem(state.cartItems, action.payload)
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default cartReducer;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check your imports, in your Preview component, you use the default import and a named import in your Collection

Thus, in your Collection component, you get a not redux-connected version, so you don’t have access to the props passed in the mapStateToProps.

Just replace `import  { CollectionItem }` with `import CollectionItem`